# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Status code was: 127

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 102, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 115, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(f"Service {self._path} unexpectedly exited. Status code was: {return_code}")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /root/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/122.0.6261.57/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127
```

I'm getting this error every time that i try to execute the webdriver in my docker container. I've searching for solutions, but still didn't getting it. What could it be?

My code:

```
import chromedriver_binary          # noqa: F401
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

I need to solve this problem faster that it can be

Comment: can you add Dockerfile?